# long keys and data are same size

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to make a symmetric encryption algorithm. My key is 256 bits, and the block size and resulting ciphertext are also 256 bit. Is there a disadvantage because the key, plaintext and ciphertext have the same size?

Answer (score 2):

Do *not* use home-brewed cryptographic algorithms for anything worth protecting. This is a complex area, where techniques that you'd never dream of are routine for crackers. There are plenty of time-tested and expert-vetted algorithms around, use one of those (after looking it up for kwnown weaknesses, and possible recommendations).

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) [block ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) assume that the message size is a multiple of the block size, much as yours. There's no intrinsic disadvantage to that, AFAIK, and it makes it much easier to process the data. If you don't want to process the data in blocks, you need a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher).

As @vonbrand has mentioned, you should **never** use such a custom cipher to encrypt any kind of sensitive data, as it **will** be trivially broken. If all you want is to have a working block cipher, you're looking for[AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), which is uncrackable, as far the top universities know.